# Lisp case with different equality predicate

Tags: common-lisp, equality, predicate

As a part of a Tic Tac Toe playing bot, I need a function that evaluates combinations of tiles to points. The code would look something like this:

```
(case combination
    ("EEEEE" 0)
    ("EEEEP" 1)
    ("EEEPE" 1)
    ("EEEPP" 2)
    ("EEPEE" 1)
    ("EEPEP" 2)
    ("EEPPE" 2)
    ("EEPPP" 3)
    ("EPEEE" 1)
    ("EPEEP" 2)
    ("EPEPE" 2)
    ("EPEPP" 3)
    ("EPPEE" 2)
    ("EPPEP" 3)
    ("EPPPE" 3)
    ("EPPPP" 4)
    ("PEEEE" 1)
    ("PEEEP" 2)
    ("PEEPE" 2)
    ("PEEPP" 3)
    ("PEPEE" 2)
    ("PEPEP" 3)
    ("PEPPE" 3)
    ("PEPPP" 4)
    ("PPEEE" 2)
    ("PPEEP" 3)
    ("PPEPE" 3)
    ("PPEPP" 4)
    ("PPPEE" 3)
    ("PPPEP" 4)
    ("PPPPE" 4)
    ("PPPPP" 5))
```

(This is not the place to discuss the value of such an approach, for it is used for reasons unrelated to the question)

The problem is that case uses a predicate that doesn't return true for identical strings that aren't the same object (hard to find if it's eq or eql). How can you change that?

EDIT: I solved the original problem by converting the string into a corresponding binary number, which can be compared using eql or used as an index in a list.

Comment: CASE uses the EQL predicate.

Comment: Pattern matching ? https://github.com/guicho271828/trivia

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `alexandria:switch` from the `alexandria` library, available from quicklisp.

```
(switch (combination :test #'string=)
  ("FOO" …)
  …)
```

Answer (score 3):

Your code just calculates `(count #\P combination)`.

Usually I would convert the string in a number and compute with it. Using  `LOGCOUNT` to get the on bits or something. Even if I were using a large `CASE`-like switch, I would convert the string once to a number, instead of doing a multitude of string comparisons.

Comment: This is why I added the part in parentheses. This code is just a placeholder I use before I invent a better points system, the numbers may be different. I need to be able to change any of these numbers arbitrarily.

Answer (score 2):

You could write a macro:

```
(defmacro string-case (key &rest forms)
  (let ((k (gensym "KEY")))
    `(let ((,k ,key))
       (cond
         ,@(loop for (str . body) in forms
                 collect `((string= ,k ,str) ,@body))))))
```

And then use it like case. Note that this macro will check each substring one at a time (up to 32 branches in your case), which is less efficient than eg looking at the first character and deciding what to do, then looking at the next character and so on (5-10 branches in your case), which is less efficient than doing what you actually intend (eg counting `#\P`) (this can be done with 5-6 easily predicted branches, or maybe 10 depending on implementation). Of these options, the second generated the most code, then the first, then the third.

Comment: I don't intend to just count the P's. This is just a placeholder before I invent a better points system.

Answer (score 2):

Another approach would be to convert `combination` to a symbol. The resulting code will look like this:

```
(case (intern combination)
  (EEEEE 0)
  (EEEEP 1)
  (EEEPE 1)
  ...)
```

But you need to keep in mind that `intern` operates at runtime in the context of current package (`*package*`), which means that if this is part of a function that is called outside of the package where it's defined, it will not work. There are 2 ways to work around this (basically, two variations of one): either intern in the package (`(intern combination <your-package>)`) or intern as keyword. In the later case, the whole form will look like this:

```
(case (intern combination :keyword)
  (:EEEEE 0)
  (:EEEEP 1)
  (:EEEPE 1)
  ...)
```

Also worth noting may be performance considerations. They shouldn't be a problem as, although `intern`ing is a rather heavy operation, initially, when it's called repeatedly on an already interned symbol it's, basically, just a dictionary lookup.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution may be to define the rules as a list, and search through the list for the matching string.

```
(defun match-combination (combination)
  (let ((rules '(("EEEEE" 0)
                 ("EEEEP" 1)
                 ("EEEPE" 1)
                         ...)))
    (cadr (find combination rules :key #'car :test #'string=))))
```